# How to install libnss-ldap in Ubuntu 10.04 without graphical interface setup?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, apt

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. And I want to install `libnss-ldap` by apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap
```

And during installation, a graphical interface setup appears.

Because I want to install it on 1000+ servers, graphical interface is out of option.

Question:

How can I install it without graphical interface setup?

`OR`

How can I install libnss-ldap without `auth-client-config  ldap-auth-client ldap-auth-config`

PS: Manually compiling is out of option too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

preseed your config:

```
echo -e " \
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/dblogin boolean false
libnss-ldap shared/ldapns/base-dn   string  dc=example,dc=com
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/binddn  string  cn=proxyuser,dc=example,dc=com
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/dbrootlogin boolean true
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/override    boolean true
libnss-ldap shared/ldapns/ldap-server   string  ldap://127.0.0.1/
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/confperm    boolean false
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/rootbinddn  string  cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
libnss-ldap shared/ldapns/ldap_version  select  3
libnss-ldap libnss-ldap/nsswitch    note    \
" | debconf-set-selections
```

install your package unattended:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
aptitude --without-recommends install libnss-ldap
```